# Reverse UITable row number from big to small (...5,4,3, 2,1)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a customCell where I have a label which shows the number of each row as 1,2,3,4..., 4 being the last row at the bottom of the table. Everything is working fine but I would like to reverse the numbers instead to be 4,3,2,1 where 4 would be the top row and 1 would be the last bottom row.

Here is the code I'm using to add the number to the label in the customCell.

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.labelRowNumber!.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)// how to reverse the indexPath.row

        return cell
    }
```

Is this possible without adding an array just to keep track of the number of each row?

FYI - I'm already reversing the content added to the table, which comes from an array `itemList.insert(dataCell, atIndex:0)`. I just need to reverse the numbers to match the content.

Thanks

Comment: Try using `String(tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - indexPath.row)`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to get the values out in reverse order:

```
cell.labelRowNumber!.text = String(count - indexPath.row)
```

Where count is the number of rows you are displaying (ie. whatever you're returning from numberOfRowsInSection). Presumably `itemList.count`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!